# Grammar of プレッシャーに晒される

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

> 不条理な暴力によるプレッシャーに晒される

after some searching, I also found these sentences:

> 絶え間ないプレッシャーにさらされる
>
> 来る日も来る日もプレッシャーにさらされる

プレッシャーに晒す, as far as i can tell, you a transitive verb can't take noun+に without a indirect object.

such as "X を/は Y に V-transitive" in general

what is going on in these instances? What is the agent of the passive verb? can pressure itself be the agent?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> プレッシャーに晒す, as far as i can tell, you a transitive verb can't take noun+に without a indirect object.

In プレッシャーにさらす, プレッシャー is the indirect object. The direct object is left out.

［XX**を**］プレッシャー**に**さらす -- active voice
→［XX**が**］プレッシャー**に**さらされる -- passive voice

> What is the agent of the passive verb? can pressure itself be the agent?

The agent of the さらす is not mentioned, either.

［YYが］［XX**を**］プレッシャーにさらす -- active voice
→［XX**が**］［YYによって］プレッシャーにさらされる -- passive voice

Comment: is the "expose oneself 《to a situation》/ 危険な状態に置く " definition of 晒すused in these sentences? That may be why i had such a hard time with it.

Comment: そうですね、「❺ 好ましくない状況の中に身を置く。『危険に身をさらす』『我が国は今敵の脅威にさらされている』」(明鏡国語辞典) にあたるのかな、と思います。。