# relative clause with direct object

Tags: relative-clauses

Generally:

AはBを食べる　<-> Bを食べるA

but i do not think i can't rearrange this in terms of

~~~B

However if it its a sentence with an indirect object as well:

> 「昔は天の川に見立てた川に笹を流して願い事をする行事なんかもあった

compared with:

> [［YYが］［XXを］プレッシャーにさらす -- active
>   voice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62621/grammar-of-%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E6%99%92%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B)

are all of the following correct?

昔は川を天の川に見立てた　<-> 昔は天の川に見立てた川

YYがXXをプレッシャーにさらす <-> YYがプレッシャーにさらすXX

私はAにBをあげる <-> 私はAにあげるB

thank you for confirming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rearrange...

AはBを食べる
→ A**が**食べるB ("B that A eats")
→ Bを食べるA ("A that eats B")

(You *usually* don't use the topic particle は in a relative clause. 「Aが食べるB」 would sound more natural than 「Aは食べるB」 in most situations.)

川を天の川に見立てた
→ 天の川に見立てた川
→ 川を見立てた天の川
<sub>(In 昔は天の川に見立てた川に笹を流して願い事をする行事なんかもあった, 昔は modifies (行事なんかも)あった, not (天の川に)見立てた.)</sub>

YYがXXをプレッシャーにさらす
→ YYがプレッシャーにさらすXX
→ XXをプレッシャーにさらすYY

私はAにBをあげる ("I give B to A")
→ 私**が**AにあげるB ("B which I give to A")
→ 私**が**BをあげるA ("A who I give B to")
→ AにBをあげる私 ("Me who gives B to A")